# Can a method be able to return different data types?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a class named `matFactory()`. Inside it, there is a method named `lastAddedObj(..)`.

The latter method receives an `ArrayList` as a parameter and returns the last added object in this list.

My problem is: I have two kind of lists, `ArrayList<Mat>` and `ArrayList<MatOfKeyPoint>` and I want the method `lastAddedObject` to be applicable for both types. As you see the method signature below:

```
public Mat lastAddedObj(ArrayList<Mat> list) {
....
....
    return list.get(size -1);
}
```

And I want this method to be able for both `ArrayList<Mat>` and `ArrayList<MatOfKeyPoint>`, because as you see above, if I passed `ArrayList<Mat>` it will return `Mat` object and if will pass `ArrayList<MatOfKeyPoint>` it will return `MatOfKeyPoint` object.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Use generics for this purpose

Comment: @VivekSingh  can u please tell me what is the difference between the: <T> and T? the return data type is <T> T  what is the difference between the two T

Comment: Is there a relation between `Mat` and `MatOfKeyPoint`, like the second extends or implements the first?

Comment: @AbbéRésina no i think there is no relation

Comment: The code inside `lastAddedJob` does not call any method on the elements of the list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this:

```
public <T> T lastAddedObj(ArrayList<T> list) {
  return list.get(size - 1);
}
```

**Explanation:**

when you're calling this method using an `ArrayList<Mat>`, the `Mat` type is inferred and the `T` (the generic type) is replaced by `Mat`. Some comments on my answer suggested that you should also mark the method as `static`, but this is not required.

Here is a tutorial about generics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: Also I would consider declaring this method as `static` in this case.

Comment: I just didn't want to change any semantics for him, it's his call for `static` for not :)

Comment: thans for the answer, can u please tell me why should it be static? and another question please, using the return data type u sed in ur answer <T>, this will Mat object if i passed Mat obj and it will be MatOfKeyPoint if i passed MatOfKeyPoint object?

Comment: for the second part of ur question in comment - Yes.

Comment: I have added some details about my answer, hope this helps.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea can u please tell me what is the difference between the: <T> and T? the return data type is <T> T what is the difference between the two T

Comment: @rmaik: The <T> is for making the method as generic(i.e. T is not an actual type, it's a template type). The T is the actual return type. Because T will be replaced with a real type, you will have the right return type based on the type inferred from the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


//define an interface which Mat & MatOfKeyPoint would implement
interface MatLister {

}

class Mat implements MatLister {
    private int value;
    Mat(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

class MatOfKeyPoint implements MatLister {
    private int key;
    MatOfKeyPoint(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public int getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }
}
class MatListTester
{
    //let the method accept ArrayList with MatLister type objects
    public static MatLister lastAddedObj(ArrayList<? extends MatLister> list) {
        return list.get(list.size() -1);
    }

    //check the type of object being passed and return the value
    public static int objValue(MatLister listElement) {
        if(listElement instanceof Mat) {
            Mat matElement = (Mat)listElement;
            return matElement.getValue();
        } else if(listElement instanceof MatOfKeyPoint) {
            MatOfKeyPoint matOfKeyPointElement = (MatOfKeyPoint)listElement;
            return matOfKeyPointElement.getKey();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ArrayList<Mat> matList = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        ArrayList<MatOfKeyPoint> matOfKeyPointList = new ArrayList<MatOfKeyPoint>();

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            matList.add(new Mat(i));
        }

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            matOfKeyPointList.add(new MatOfKeyPoint(i));
        }

        MatLister lastAddedObjectMat = lastAddedObj(matList);
        MatLister lastAddedObjectMatOfKeyPoint = lastAddedObj(matOfKeyPointList);
        System.out.println(objValue(lastAddedObjectMat));
        System.out.println(objValue(lastAddedObjectMatOfKeyPoint));

    }
}
```